# How can I perform bag of words model for each column in the data frame according to the Year-Week?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
 Year-Week  Job_list   Comments_2
    2019-01    Doc-1      Doc-1
    2019-01    Doc-2      Doc-2
    2019-01    Doc-3      Doc-3
    2019-02    Doc-4      Doc-4
    2019-03    Doc-5      Doc-5
```

I want the output separately for each column according to year-week after applying bag of words model

Comment: Can you please tell us more clearly about the requirement.

Comment: How can I apply bag of words on this data frame?

Comment: you can do a group by w.r.t to the column you need data to be grouped. In this case it is year-week and store them separately in a list or a dataframe column. And further apply CountVectorizer of TfIdf vectorizer on the list or a dataframe to get the bag of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby` to group the output according to year-week.

After that you can use `.apply(list)` to transform the grouped output into a list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-01', 'Doc-1', 'Doc-1'], ['2019-01', 'Doc-2', 'Doc-2'],['2019-01','Doc-3','Doc-3'],['2019-02','Doc-4','Doc-4'],['2019-03','Doc-5','Doc-5']],columns= ['Year-Week', 'Job_list', 'Comments_2'])

#Use groupby and then .apply(list)
job_list_grouped = df.groupby('Year-Week')['Job_list'].apply(list)
print(job_list_grouped)
```

The output looks like that:

```
Year-Week
2019-01    [Doc-1, Doc-2, Doc-3]
2019-02                  [Doc-4]
2019-03                  [Doc-5]
```

You could simply do the same for the other column.
And from there you can use it to transform it to anything you need.

***EDIT:***

You can use the module `Counter` from the library `collections` for that!

Here is my new code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-01', 'Doc-1', 'Doc-1'], ['2019-01', 'Doc-2', 'Doc-2'],['2019-01','Doc-3','Doc-3'],['2019-02','Doc-4','Doc-4'],['2019-03','Doc-5','Doc-5']],columns= ['Year-Week', 'Job_list', 'Comments_2'])

job_list_grouped = df.groupby('Year-Week')['Job_list'].apply(list).apply(Counter)
print(job_list_grouped)
print(job_list_grouped.to_dict())
```

Note how I only added another `apply` to the end of the `groupby` function.

The first print puts out:

```
Year-Week
2019-01    {'Doc-1': 1, 'Doc-2': 1, 'Doc-3': 1}
2019-02                            {'Doc-4': 1}
2019-03                            {'Doc-5': 1}
```

If you need to have this in a dictionary format you can simply add `to_dict()` to do this:

```
{'2019-01': Counter({'Doc-1': 1, 'Doc-2': 1, 'Doc-3': 1}), '2019-02': Counter({'Doc-4': 1}), '2019-03': Counter({'Doc-5': 1})}
```

Don´t worry about the `Counter` around your dictionaries. It still behaves exactly like a `dict`.

Comment: @Umama Disha If my answer was what you were looking for I would be happy if you accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I apply bag of words model for each column and the output will be shown according to year-week?

Comment: @UmamaDisha see my edit. Is that what your are looking for?

Comment: Thanks!it works but i want the output with header and  there is no header in the output!

Comment: Where exactly do you want to have the header?

Comment: year_week  job_list  Comments_2 i want these header in the output

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: df['bow_job_list']=df.Job_list.apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(" "))) this code gives the output which i want. Thanks for your help